# Git - GPG signing fails after commit name & email change

Tags: git, gnupg

I have a local git repository with a bunch of commits made with my real name and personal email. I want to push these to GitHub, but without using my personal details.

I've rewritten the name and email for each commit using the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter \
"GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='github_username'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='github_username@users.noreply.github.com'; \
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='github_username'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='github_username@users.noreply.github.com';" HEAD
```

All looks fine when a do a `git log` after this. My personal email is nowhere to be seen.

I then try to GPG sign every commit using:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all
```

But on the very first commit I get the following error:

```
Rewrite 1124486cba6a6f6432adb24f7c66833d860b191f (1/38) (1 seconds passed, remaining 37 predicted)    
gpg: skipped "My Real Name <my_real_email@gmail.com>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
could not write rewritten commit
```

Where is it getting my old username and password from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `-- --all` at the end was the culprit. Changing that to `HEAD` instead worked fine.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' HEAD
```